# Using php in CSS ID/Class name

Tags: php, html, css

can we use php in css ID/Class name ? ( in PHP Page)
like this

```
<div class="box <?php echo $something ; ?>">
```

or

```
.sample-<?php echo $something; ?> {
     /* CSS Styles */
 }
```

thanks

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: More context, please.  Where are you doing this?  Not in your css stylesheet, unless you make it a php file (not recommended).  But the short answer is *yes*, on a php page.

Comment: yeah i meant php page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ok as long as its in a php file (with .php extension)

```
<div class="box <?php echo $something ; ?>">
```

This however,

```
 .sample-<?php echo $something; ?> {
     /* CSS Styles */
 }
```

Please never do this. There's really no reason to. Furthermore, the purpose of CSS is for styling your webpage not handling server side scripts

Comment: Dynamic styles are indeed required from time to time. Can you explain a way for the OP to achieve this in an elegant way?

Comment: If you want dynamic styling you can use Javascript to achieve that

Comment: That's one way to do it, though I'd generally prefer PHP, as it is less brittle. Consider a web site designer where the user's choice of background colour is stored in the database as a hex string. It needs to be rendered in some way to reflect this choice on the client, so either in a JavaScript block or a CSS block. Either way, you'd serve a dynamic asset, and probably cache it in a server-side file for efficiency.